# C# Emgu BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 returns black image

Tags: c#, wpf, emgucv

Hey and thanks for your time.
im working on some opencv in C#(Emgu) and trying to diplay the forground from BackgroundSubtractorMOG2
but with no luck  here is my code

```
        internal Bitmap AdaptableBackgroundSubtraction(Bitmap org, int history = 2, bool detectShadows = true, int threshold = 16)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageorg = org.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
        var forgroundmask = imageorg;
        var mDetector = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history, threshold, detectShadows);

        mDetector.Apply(imageorg, forgroundmask, 0.5);
        return forgroundmask.ToBitmap();
    }
```

i have tried a few things and changing parameters but i dont get any results. any help will be appreciated

[Picture of program running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6FWS.png)

Link to the full code if needed
https://gitlab.com/Clipcometx/semesterportefolje/-/tree/master/Machinelearning/ComputerVision

Answer (score 0):

According to attached picture, you set the max hue value to 255, while the hue range is 0-179.